# Geometrical meaning of substituting third variable as a function of other two when doing a surface integral in differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Suppose I have to integrate $dy \wedge dz$ over the unit hemisphere centered at the origin. I have:

$$ \int_S dy \wedge dz$$

The equation of hemisphere is given as $z=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$, I have $dz = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y } dy$. I can substitute this expression of $dz$ in the above to get:

$$ \int_S  \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}dy \wedge dx $$

Conceptually, what exactly happened in the above substitution? I am a bit confused because $dy \wedge dz$ is an area element in the $y-z$ plane and $dy \wedge dx$ is an area element in the $x-y$ plane. Note that I'm using the interpretation of two form as something you project the area spanned by two vectors into.

Answer (score 0):

The chosen coordinate chart for the upper hemisphere $S_+$ of the unit sphere $S$ is
$$\tag{1}
\{x^2+y^2\le 1\}\ni (x,y)\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\end{pmatrix}\in S_+.
$$
Intuitively and geometrically the $2$-form $dx\wedge dy$ is an oriented surface element that is spanned by the tangent vectors on $S$ in the $x$- and $y$-direction. In $\mathbb R^3$ we know that this can be expressed by a cross product
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}\\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\\\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial y}\\\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\\frac{-x}{z}\end{pmatrix}\times
\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\\frac{-y}{z}\end{pmatrix}=
\frac{1}{z}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
Then we have a vector valued surface integral
$$\tag{2}
\int_{S_+}dx\wedge dy=\int_{x^2+y^2\le 1}\frac{1}{z}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}\,dx\,dy.
$$
The integration variables $x,y$ on the RHS of this formula are ordinary numbers.

When you want to consider
$$
\int_{S_+}dy\wedge dz
$$
I think you should use the chart
$$\tag{2}
\{y^2+z^2\le 1\}\ni (y,z)\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{1-y^2-z^2}\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}\in S_+.
$$
and repeat the whole exercise. But note that the hemisphere $S_+$ is now a different one.

Comment: Hmm I feel like you didn't understand what my doubt actually was

Comment: In $\mathbb R^3$ we have three basis one forms $dx,dy,dz$. Between them there is no relationship $dz=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}dy$. To me they are just symbols that determine what kind of integral over the surface we have. A very instructive exercise could be to figure out the two forms that can conventiently be used to calculate the surface measure of $S$. This integral is not vector valued. Confusing ? At least that was it for me until a few months ago. Let me know how your studies are going. I feel like I learn a lot from your questions.

Comment: What was your doubt ?

Comment: Thanks for the support Kurt, it means a lot to me :) . My question how is it possible that we are able to relate areas which exist on two orthogonal planes. By the way, I'd say there is a bit more to think about than seeing them as symbols. I would highly recommend you check out the final chapter of Visual Differential Geometry by Tristan Needham. I am not sure if you know already, but they can be thought of also as stack of sheets and such

Comment: By substituting $z$ in terms of $x,y$ into $dz$ I related the area on y-x plane to z-x one. Which I don't think is possible since they are two perpendicular plane. For instance, if we had two perpendicular vector, we can't project on onto the other and then describe the components of one in terms of the other because projection will kill it

Comment: That is my point. $dx\wedge dy$ is not an area in the $x-y$ plane. It is an oriented area on the curved surface of $S$. The other point in my last comment was that the surface of the sphere as we know it $4\pi r^2$ is calculated with *yet another* surface integral that uses not oriented surface elements. They are rather scalars.

Comment: I think I need to think more on what you said in the end

Comment: I think you've made a small error. What you really should've said is dx wedge dy evaluated at the tangent vectors gives the area. Generally speaking dx wedge dy takes the tangent vectors and projects them down onto x-y plane